# In marionette mvc pattern, where to put different get API calls

Tags: javascript, marionette

For example I have the following server routes set up for my user entity:

```
GET /users/      // gets collection of users
GET /users/:id   // gets user :id
GET /users/me    // gets the current user
```

At the beginning of my app I want to get the current user from the server and store it... Something along the lines of:

```
App.addInitializer(function () {
    $.get('/users/me')
        .done(function processCurrentUser (userJson) {
            App.user = new User(userJson);
        });
});
```

My question is where this API call should actually reside. Would it be better to have something along the lines of:

```
App.addInitializer(function () {
    App.user = new User();
    App.user.fetchMe(); // performs the api call above
});
```

Or should I be doing something inside of a controller?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When doing a fetch, I always worry about how its `asyn` behavior is going to affect the components that depend on that data. If there are no downriver components that will need the data before it can be reasonably expected to return, then there's technically nothing wrong with your approach.

There is, however, another possible way of loading your globals. What I often do (and for a user's list, too, it so happens) is bootstrap the data to the initial load page. I generally load it on the `window` variable. So for your example, in your **backend** template,

```
<script>
  window.globals = {};
  window.globals.currentUser = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.User))
</script>
```

Of course, you can replace `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.User))` (we use C#) with your favorite backend model.

Then in your app start you're guaranteed to have the models:

```
App.addInitializer(function () {
    App.user = new User(window.globals.currentUser);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I thought about doing this as well and might end up going to this. To avoid the problem you're describing I ended up using $.ajax and setting the async option to false. In this particular app I don't need the data until the marionette app has begun, so this should be fine in my case, although bootstrapping probably solves the more general problem.

Comment: This method has worked really well, and it's also and [official recommendation](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) by the Backbone framework.